# Find Website Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a button that finds the website if it's in Salesforce or if blank, uses the email domain or uses the Company name. Someone decided to enter "http://No website (Date)" in a host of Website fields which means the code I'm using thinks this is the website and goes no further. I need to include in my code something that says If Website Begins with "http://No website" check the email.

The code I'm using is:

```
var website = '{!JSENCODE( Customer_Support_Survey__c.Company_Website__c )}';
var email = '{!Customer_Support_Survey__c.Customer_Contact_Email__c}';
var company = '{!JSENCODE( Customer_Support_Survey__c.Company_Name__c )}';
var targetURL = '';

// IF WEBSITE FIELD IS POPULATED WE GO THERE, NATURALLY

if(website != ''){

// CHECK IF WE NEED TO ADD http:// OR NOT
if(website.indexOf('//') != -1)
targetURL = website;
else
targetURL = 'http://' + website;
}

// NEXT WE CHECK OUT THE DOMAIN OF THE EMAIL ADDRESS

else if(email != ''){

var domain = email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1,email.length);

// WE FILTER OUT COMMON EMAIL DOMAINS
if(domain!='gmail.com' && domain!='yahoo.com' && domain!='hotmail.com' && domain!='me.com' && domain!='excite.com' && domain!='aol.com')
targetURL = 'http://' + domain;
}

// IF NO TARGET FOUND YET WE TAKE A STAB USING COMPANY

if(targetURL==''){

targetURL = 'http://';

// FAIR ASSUMPTION IS TO SWAP '&' for 'and'
company = company.replace(/\&/g,'and');

// STRIP OUT INVALID DOMAIN CHARACTERS
targetURL += company.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9|\-]/g,'') + '.com.au';

}

// FINALLY WE OPEN A NEW WINDOW DIRECTED TO OUR TARGET URL

window.open(targetURL,'_blank','',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per OP you just need to check if your website field start with "http://No website".

For this, You can use startwith function to check if variable website start with above string

```
var str = "http://No website sdfsdfsdfsdf ";
var n = str.startsWith("http://No website");
alert(n);
```

If you intend to validate the compete website value "http://No website" string then you will have to use generic regular expression something like below.

```
var re = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
if (!re.test(url)) { 
    alert("url error");
    return false;
}
```